# What is the difference between browser.pause() and browser.enterRepl()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In protractor, there is the [`browser.pause()` function](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.pause):

> Beta (unstable) `pause` function for debugging webdriver tests. Use
>   browser.pause() in your test to enter the protractor debugger from
>   that point in the control flow.

```
element(by.id('foo')).click();
browser.pause();
// Execution will stop before the next click action.
element(by.id('bar')).click();
```

And, also, there is a less-known one - [`browser.enterRepl()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.enterRepl):

> Beta (unstable) `enterRepl` function for entering the repl loop from any
>   point in the control flow. Use browser.enterRepl() in your test. Does
>   not require changes to the command line (no need to add 'debug').

```
element(by.id('foo')).click();
browser.enterRepl();
// Execution will stop before the next click action.
element(by.id('bar')).click();
```

From the provided documentation and examples, it is clear that they both are used for debugging the tests. But, it is not clear, what is the difference between the two.

When should we use `pause()` and when `enterRepl()`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's explained in the [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) in general, but I'll try to get a bit deeper.

Protractor has [two modes](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/2.1.0/lib/debugger/modes) for debugging: *DebuggerRepl* and *CommandRepl*.

*Repl* here stands for *Read-eval-print-loop* which usually means that whatever command you type in, it gets evaluated right away in the current context and you are provided with a result immediately. For example, the console in *Chrome Developer Tools* is kinda a *REPL* for *Chrome's* implementation of *JavaScript/DOM*, or when you run `node` in terminal, you get a *REPL* for *Node.js's JavaScript* context - you can type commands and get the result.

---

When you use `browser.pause()` you are activating *DebuggerRepl*. It brings you a *Repl* where you can execute commands of this mode. You usually see this list of commands in the terminal:

```
press c to continue to the next webdriver command
press d to continue to the next debugger statement
type "repl" to enter interactive mode
type "exit" to break out of interactive mode
press ^C to exit
```

So you can go to the next WebDriver command using `c` command or jump to the next `browser.pause()` statement in your test using `d` command. They are executed right away as you use them. So this mode basically allows you to **jump over page states** and explore the result. (Note: this mode provides [more commands](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2.1.0/lib/debugger/modes/debuggerRepl.js#L4); they do work, but I'm not sure what is the meaning of their output and if they are useful for a Protractor user at all.)

---

When you use `browser.enterRepl()` you are activating *CommandRepl mode*. It allows you to use *Protractor* methods which you would use in tests, but in an interactive mode. You get access to `element`, `browser` and `protractor` objects, so you could run for example:

```
> $('.hello').getText();
> 'World'
```

It prints you back the result immediately, so it's sort of a sandbox where you can query the DOM **on the current page state** and see the results.

As you may have noticed, the `browser.pause()` list of commands has a line:

```
type "repl" to enter interactive mode
```

It means that when you are in *DebuggerRepl mode*, you can execute the `repl` command to activate *CommandRepl mode* for the **current page state** where you've just run `browser.pause()`, so you can play with DOM as if you've just used `browser.enterRepl()`. You can go back to *DebuggerRepl mode* using the `exit` command. But if you've entered to *CommandRepl mode* using `browser.enterRepl()`, you can't switch to *DebuggerRepl mode*.

Also, *CommandRepl mode* can be activated with a feature called *elementExplorer*. It can be used without any written tests; it just opens a URL in *CommandRepl mode*.

---

tl;dr

To summarize, I believe that they supposed to be used according to how they are called.

`browser.pause()` - I want a browser to pause exactly in that place so I can see what's happening on the page. Then, on my command, I want it to jump to the next state so I can see what is happening here. If I need more information for current state, I can run `repl` and use the *Protractor API* (`browser`, `element`, `protractor`) to investigate. I can then `exit` this mode and continue jumping through states.

`browser.enterRepl()` - I want a browser to pause exactly in that place and let me investigate a page using the *Protractor API* (`browser`, `element`, `protractor`) right away, and I don't need to be able to jump between states of the page.

Comment: That's a really great explanation! Thanks so much! Created a follow up issue here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2349.

Comment: For anyone who wants to know, the `elementExplorer` feature that Michael describes can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#testing-out-protractor-interactively). Basically, run `protractor --elementExplorer` in your console, use `browser.get('http://(url).com')` to load a web page, then Protractor to your heart's content with regular commands (`element(by.css('a')).click()` and so forth).

Comment: so, `browser.pause()` + `repl` = `browser.enterRepl()`?

Comment: Is there something equivalent[enterRepl()] in slenium Java?

Comment: They took the "repl" command out of browser.pause(); so now you have to use browser.enterRepl(); in order to interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor version 5.3 with Node version 8.10 **do not support** `browser.pause()` anymore. More info [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307).

There's a chance you can do what you need with [protractor async aswait](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md).